# Pasting value at the intersection of Row X and Column Y

Tags: excel, intersection, paste

I need to keep records of my students' grades for each studied subject. I already have an automated corrector for the exams, and whenever this corrector reaches the results I need it to open a second sheet and paste that grade on the intersection between the student's ID number (Column A) and respective subject (Row 1).

I have about 5,300 students and 17 different subjects.

Actually, I am able to do that already, but I use Excel formulas in each of the more than 10,000 cells of that sheet that "search" the grade according to my criteria. Now, can you imagine how slooooow that thing works!

My concise question is: Is there any way of performing the intended task, but faster?

Comment: Can you give some details on how exactly it gets the grades? Different files? What do they look like?

After that, we might want to know what languages you are familiar with, code, database? Just excel? After that, we can give you an answer you can use, otherwise we'll just post something you might not know

Comment: Hi Stephen. Wow, that was fast! Well, I'm familiar with Excel VBA. Actually I used VBA to create this "corrector". As all exams are answered in a standard sheet for 20 questions, I have a VBA form, opened according to each subject, where I right the students' ID, the date and then feed checkboxes with an "x" for each wrongly answered question. That way, besides calculating the final grade, I also have control of "how difficult" each question is by calculating how many students answered it wronlgy. All this information is recorded into a single sheet, but in a row-after-row basis. Thank you!!!

Comment: Please show the Worksheet data structure with sample data and your code snippet, clearly highlighting the problematic part of your solution, so we could help. Thanks and regards,

Comment: Stephen, I've already tried Index-Match, but I was not able to "paste" value into the cell found. I've thought about using a Find method, but that is still confusing for me. Thank you once again for yout help.

Comment: Hi Alex! I was really afraid any of you would ask me that, rsrsrs... Can you please tell me how to post it here? I could write a part of my code, but I don't know how to paste an image of it. Thank you.

Comment: I tried to paste my code to find the grade here, but it is toooooo long, and there's not enough space for writing it here. But basically, what I am not able to figure out is: as I get the grade, I need it to open a second sheet and, in that one, search the students ID (all in column A) and match it with the subject in row 1 (names are: CBF, DGR, SOB, SAC, EMG, ...) and paste the grade on that intersection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not post any actual question. I guess you want to perform the task in your title, faster than you currently do it.
I guess slowness is due to your summary worksheet having too many formulas, which are recalculated upon each change. If so, your solution would be either:

1. Once you find the right cell to place the grade, paste it as value, not keeping the formula. The (step-by-step) code below does this. You have to call it after computing the grade.
2. Disabling automatic calculation, and enabling it only at the end of one working session (e.g.). You can do it via menus, or via VBA.

`Sub paste_grade(ByVal stud As Long, ByVal subj As Integer, ByVal gr As Double)
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Dim studrow As Long
        studrow = WorksheetFunction.Match(stud, ws.Range("A:A"), 0)
        Dim trg As Range
        Set trg = ws.Cells(studrow, subj + 1)
        trg.Value = gr
    End Sub`

You will have to adapt it slightly, e.g., `gr` or `subj` as a string. In the last case, you will have to use again `WorksheetFunction.Match` on row `1:1`. From your post, I guess you know how to do it.

Comment: Hi sancho! Thank you so much for your help! The second option worked just perfectly for me! I really didn't know I could "retard" the calculation and it was just what I needed. I must confess I still didn't try your first suggestion, but I will! Thanks a lot once again and Merry Xmas!!!

Comment: I am glad to see this resolved. It looks like Sancho's ability to predict and conquer is greater than mine, though I'm not an excel dude. I will upvote at least!